# Regex is greedy and grabs past the secod quotation

Tags: regex

I am creating some regex that should replace `>` characters in an expression with `&gt;`. So in `expression="x > 10"` it should become `expression="x &gt; 10"`. But if my expression doesn't contain a `>` then the regex is greedy and grabs `>` outside of quotation marks. For example the following gets incorrectly converted: `expression="9a / 3b - 10c" > foo="67 + 34"` to `expression="9a / 3b - 10c" &gt; foo="67 + 34"`

Do you know how I can make my regex not search past the second `"` (or `'`)?

My regex is: `(expression=["|'].*?>)(.*?["|'])`

Here is an example of the error occurring: https://regex101.com/r/aQuPmd/1/

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aQuPmd/3

Comment: `.` matches almost anything, and `>`, too. So, use `[^>]` instead.